AssemblyScript compiler mentions option noUnsafe. But unsafe does not work, gives compiler error. How to use unsafe to disable runtime bound check?
I am writing a module where I want to maximize performance, so I would like to use the unsafe keyword to disable all run time bound checks.
It also looks like this is supported, because "asc" has a compiler option "noUnsafe", presumably to enable usage of unsafe.
However, when I use unsafe in my code, I get a compiler error - unable to find the name "unsafe".
What am I doing wrong, how can I use unsafe in my code?
I tried:
export unsafe functionName(): void {

    // my code

}

and
export functionName(): void {

    unsafe {

    // my code

    }
}

Both did not work, gave same error.
I even tried putting @unsafe, instead of unsafe, did not work.
